# Powering an electric keyboard

Tags: power-supply, power

May I use a power supply of 13V@300ma instead of a 9V@850ma required by device(keyboard), without harming the device?

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not a good idea. You're applying about 144% of the Keyboard's rated voltage - seems likely to ruin something. And you'd be looking for 283% of the rated current from the power supply - seems likely to ruin that, too.